# Conditional (ternary) Operator to set the state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, random, ecmascript-6

i am new with Reactjs and doing a game to practice.I want to change the state inside a clickHandler function with a conditional Operator. But don't now if i can do that and my game is not working properly.

```
clickHandler(){
let tripsOne = Math.round(Math.round((this.state.amountOfGold / this.state.cargoOne) + 0.5))
let hoursOne= (tripsOne*2 + tripsOne*(this.state.distance/this.state.speedOne)).toFixed(2)
let tripsTwo = Math.round(Math.round((this.state.amountOfGold / this.state.cargoTwo) + 0.5))
let hoursTwo= (tripsTwo*2 + tripsTwo*(this.state.distance/this.state.speedTwo)).toFixed(2)
this.setState({tripsOne: tripsOne, hoursOne: hoursOne, tripsTwo: tripsTwo, hoursTwo: hoursTwo, showData: true})
hoursOne < hoursTwo ? this.setState({scoreOne: this.state.scoreOne +1, youWon:true}) : this.setState({scoreTwo: this.state.scoreTwo +1})
}
```

I need that the last line of this functions works in order to give the victory to the right player.

with console.log i realize that the value of hoursOne(hours player one needs to transport the gold) and hoursTwo is catched and the conditional operator sometimes works in the wrong way.

Feel free to try the game: `https://leonelav.github.io/star-wars-react/`

When we click `Play` the winner should be the player who transport the given amount of gold in less time. All the travel is made at same speed and in each trip we need to add 1 hour more to charge the gold and another to descharge.

Comment: *"with console.log i realize that the value of hoursOne(hours player one needs to transport the gold) and hoursTwo is catched and the conditional operator sometimes works in the wrong way"* Say what now?

Comment: Yeah, your code looks generally fine and there isn't anything special about React that would make this act funky. Can you take another stab at explaining the exact problem you're seeing?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @samanime: No, setting state based on state using the non-callback `setState` is never okay. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're breaking a React state rule: If you're setting state based on state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`, **not** the version that accepts the state directly. From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> ...
>
> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object.

So you need to recast that as a single `setState` call returning the new state, something along these lines:

```
clickHandler(){
    this.setState(state => {
        let tripsOne = Math.round(Math.round((state.amountOfGold / state.cargoOne) + 0.5))
        let hoursOne= (tripsOne*2 + tripsOne*(state.distance/state.speedOne)).toFixed(2)
        let tripsTwo = Math.round(Math.round((state.amountOfGold / state.cargoTwo) + 0.5))
        let hoursTwo= (tripsTwo*2 + tripsTwo*(state.distance/state.speedTwo)).toFixed(2)
        let newState = {
            tripsOne: tripsOne, hoursOne: hoursOne, tripsTwo: tripsTwo, hoursTwo: hoursTwo, showData: true,
        };
        if (hoursOne < hoursTwo) {
            newState.scoreOne = state.scoreOne + 1;
            newState.youWon = true;
        } else {
            newSate.scoreTwo = state.scoreTwo + 1;
        }
        return newState;
    });
}
```

...or if you **really** want to use the conditional, you could use spread properties (a Stage 3 proposal, supported by transpilers, present in cutting-edge browsers like current Chrome and Firefox):

```
clickHandler(){
    this.setState(state => {
        let tripsOne = Math.round(Math.round((state.amountOfGold / state.cargoOne) + 0.5))
        let hoursOne= (tripsOne*2 + tripsOne*(state.distance/state.speedOne)).toFixed(2)
        let tripsTwo = Math.round(Math.round((state.amountOfGold / state.cargoTwo) + 0.5))
        let hoursTwo= (tripsTwo*2 + tripsTwo*(state.distance/state.speedTwo)).toFixed(2)
        return {
            tripsOne: tripsOne, hoursOne: hoursOne, tripsTwo: tripsTwo, hoursTwo: hoursTwo, showData: true,
            ...(hoursOne < hoursTwo ? {scoreOne: state.scoreOne + 1, youWon: true} : {scoreTwo: scoreTwo + 1})
        };
    });
}
```

...but I wouldn't.